# Printing T.Values from Sorted Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

im trying to print some Values from my sorted list, but they dont come as i want.

The problem here is that the T.Value its a new class created.

```
public SortedDictionary<string, Node> nodeMap = new SortedDictionary<string, Node>();

(...)

foreach (Node n in nodeMap.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
```

Here is the output:[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should override a `ToString()` method in your `Node` class with what you expect at the output.

Comment: Of course!! Im so sad ... Thanks for the tip, its working now, i think im just tired